# Facebook sharer title customization

Tags: facebook, title, facebook-sharer

Is there a way to influence the title of a site when it's being shared on Facebook that's separate from setting the `<title>` in the `<head>` tag?

I want to have a title for visitors of the site but a different text for the facebook sharer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a `<meta property="og:title" content="Your title here" />` tag should do the trick.